# How to pull ECR images to cross account access?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I've organizational/multi AWS accounts. The ECR images are available on one organizational account, needs to pull these ECR images to ECS of another organizational account. While attempting this getting an error

> Cannotpullcontainererror: pull image manifest has been retried 1
> time(s): failed to resolve ref
> 189426755769.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ecr-dev-apps:1.0.0: pulling from host 123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com failed
> with status code [manifests 1.0.0]: 403 Forbidden

I could not find any documentation or guidelines on how to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Here's the documentation you are looking for https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/sharing-amazon-ecr-repositories-with-multiple-accounts-using-aws-organizations/

Comment: Thanks @James Z, its helpful, I've managed to pull the images from centralized ECR now.